# regex to match words that doesn't contain symbols

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture words that come after a certain pattern `\d+"`, I want to capture all the words after the pattern until "&" or a number is found in the word.

this is what I have so far

```
import re
tests = ['the size will be 12" QTR', 'size is 7" gnh H&M','size is 12" GNH.M gm H&M', 'sizes are 12" QTR gm Best&SAP for all ages', 'size is 14" qtr 14GM']
for i in tests:
    temp = re.search('\d+"\s+([A-Za-z.\s]+)', i).groups()[0]
    print(temp)
```

the expected output is

```
QTR
gnh
GNH.M gm
QTR gm
qtr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\d+"\s*([^\d&]+)(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x20pbo/1). *Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `"` - a double quote
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^\d&]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than a digit and `&`
- `(?!\S)` - the next char must be end of string or a whitespace.

See the Python demo:

```py
import re
tests = ['the size will be 12" QTR', 'size is 7" gnh H&M','size is 12" GNH.M gm H&M', 'sizes are 12" QTR gm Best&SAP for all ages', 'size is 14" qtr 14GM']
for test in tests:
    match = re.search(r'\d+"\s*([^\d&]+)(?!\S)', test)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Output:

```
QTR
gnh
GNH.M gm
QTR gm
qtr
```

Answer (score 1):

first replace all characters of word  that contain `&` with `&` then run your code like this:

```py
import re
tests = ['the size will be 12" QTR', 'size is 7" gnh H&M','size is 12" GNH.M gm H&M', 'sizes are 12" QTR gm Best&SAP for all ages', 'size is 14" qtr 14GM']
for j,i in enumerate(tests):
    for word in i.split():
        if "&" in word:
            i = i.replace(word, '&'*len(word))
    tests[j] = i
    temp = re.search('\d+"\s+([A-Za-z.\s]+)', i).groups()[0]
    print(temp)

print(tests)
```

output:

```
QTR
gnh 
GNH.M gm 
QTR gm 
qtr
```

after running this code your `tests list` become like this:

```
['the size will be 12" QTR',
 'size is 7" gnh &&&',
 'size is 12" GNH.M gm &&&',
 'sizes are 12" QTR gm &&&&&&&& for all ages',
 'size is 14" qtr 14GM']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a non-capturing group `(?:\d+\w+|\w+&|$)` to match all words until the `&` or a number is found in the word.

```py
import re
tests = ['the size will be 12" QTR', 'size is 7" gnh H&M',
            'size is 12" GNH.M gm H&M', 'sizes are 12" QTR gm Best&SAP for all ages',
            'size is 14" qtr 14GM']
for i in tests:
    temp = re.search('\d+"\s+(.*?)\s?(?:\d+\w+|\w+&|$)', i).groups()[0]
    print(temp)
```

```
QTR
gnh
GNH.M gm
QTR gm
qtr
```

Regex101 [sample](https://regex101.com/r/jLBipt/1)